# Render partial in new site, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so far i created an new controller with:

```
rails g controller home settings
```

In the settings.html.erb i want to display an partial so that i simply added one line:

```
<%= render "categories/index", :locals => {:categories => @categories} %>
```

So my categories/_index.html.erb looks like this, and worked:

```
<% for category in @categories do %>
 <tr>
 <td><%= category.typ %></td>    
 <td><%= link_to "Löschen", category,:class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sind sie sicher?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
  <%= form_for Category.new do |f| %>
   <td> <%= f.text_field :typ, :class => "input-small" %></td>    
   <td><%= f.submit "Speichern", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
</div>
```

But now when i open localhost:3000/home/settings i get the error:

NoMethodError in Home#settings

Showing C:/Sites/rublesql/app/views/categories/_index.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #10):

```
7:     <th></th>
8:   </tr>
9: 
10:  <% for category in @categories do %>
11:   <tr>
12:     <td><%= category.typ %></td>
```

So my question is what did i wrong?

Categories controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @categories = Category.all
end
def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to categories_path
end
def create
@category = Category.new(params[:category])
@category.save
redirect_to categories_path
end
end
```

Comment: Check to make sure your `@categories` is not nil.  You could do this before  the `%= render...` call.

Comment: could you post some code please?

Answer (score 1):

It means the `@categories` instance variable hasn't been set.
Check in your controller that it sets `@categories = xx`.

Comment: my categories controller :def index
  @categories = Category.all
 end

Answer (score 1):

Three things I notice:

You're mixing notations with the partial. Previously you would do, `render partial: "x", locals: {}`, now you can drop the `partial` key and just send the view path in, but if you choose to do this you also remove the `locals:` key:

```
<%= render "categories/index", {categories: @categories} %>
```

Also: 
`{:categories => @categories}` will make `categories` your local, not `@categories`.
However, your instanced @categories should pass through as well, so it isn't your issue.

Finally: 
@categories isn't set (or if it is, it becomes nil). Either make sure your controller correctly assigns it, or otherwise check `.nil?` or for `.present?` before attempting to loop through them.

Comment: what do you mean with @categories isnt set?

Comment: I mean either the code that sets `@categories = (something)` isn't called, or it sets the value to nil, or otherwise, later the value is set to nil. Place a debugger before the end of the def where the view is rendered, check it's value, and work your way forward/backward from there.

Comment: i added my controller to the question

Comment: The issue is that you're setting the value in the home settings controller. In the Settings context probably does not know about categories.